# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character when we try to parse a JSON

Tags: python, json

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character error when i try to parse a JSON string.

```
import json
import pprint

json_data = None
with open("C:\\Users\\75\\OneDrive\\PROJECT P1\\Work_1.0\\CBP\\server.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    json_data = json.loads(data)

pprint.pprint(json_data)
f.close()
jsonString = json.dumps(json_data,default = str)
jsonFile = open("converted.json", "w")
jsonFile.write(jsonString)
jsonFile.close()
```

Requirement is to import unformatted dump data from a text file and convert into JSON and write it into a .json file using python

Getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\\Users\\75\\OneDrive\\PROJECT P1\\Work_1.0\\CBP\\server.txt", line 11, in <module>
    json_data = json.loads(data)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads    
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode    
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 124 (char 123)
```

Comment: Have you looked at the file with a hex dump to see what's at character 123?

Comment: What do you mean by unformatted, and formatted? `Unformatted` sounds like "not really JSON", in which case you need to open it as plain text, fix it, and save it. All you are currently doing is changing the file extension. That hardly seems like the point of the exercise.

Comment: ..Also, `f` was closed as soon as the `with` terminated. Your `f.close` isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had encountered same and To solve the error, set the strict keyword argument to False in the call to json.loads().

```
json_data = json.loads(data, strict=False)
```

so your code could be like below:

```
import json
import pprint

json_data = None
with open("C:\\Users\\75\\OneDrive\\PROJECT P1\\Work_1.0\\CBP\\server.txt", 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()
    json_data = json.loads(data, strict=False)

pprint.pprint(json_data)
f.close()
jsonString = json.dumps(json_data,default = str)
jsonFile = open("converted.json", "w")
jsonFile.write(jsonString)
jsonFile.close()
```